# Text- align in css working for <td> but not for <th>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center align my text in the table. However, it works only for the td but not for th.

HTML & CSS for table, th, td:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  text-align: center;
}
th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><font size=6>Item name</font>
    </th>
    <th><font size=6>Brand</font>
    </th>
    <th><font size=6>Category</font>
    </th>
    <th><font size=6>Price</font>
    </th>
    <th><font size=6>Date of purchase</font>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><font size=4>{{ wish[4] }}</font>
    </td>
    <td><font size=4>{{ wish[6] }}</font>
    </td>
    <td><font size=4>{{ wish[5] }}</font>
    </td>
    <td><font size=4>{{ wish[7] }}</font>
    </td>
    <td><font size=4>{{ wish[3] }}</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you place your HTML code as well..

Comment: can you post your full code. I tried and it worked well

Comment: Seems to works for me. http://jsbin.com/zexopo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @oreo Do you have it hosted somewhere? I'm guessing there might be some other CSS interfering

Comment: here is a screeshot of my output "http://i.imgur.com/o5kaMrz.png"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your th is being overwritten somewhere else.

You can do this although I don't recommend it.

```
th,td {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine. Some other CSS Code elsewhere must be conflicting with it.

You can use `!important` after your attribute values. It should work fine.